# UITextField doesn't work

Tags: view, textfield, manual

In a TabBar-Application I have on the view a small one, in which I can draw. Works perfect.

With that code:

```
UITextField * textFieldRounded = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 45.0, 260.0, 50)];
textFieldRounded.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
textFieldRounded.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; //text color
textFieldRounded.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];  //font size
textFieldRounded.placeholder = @"<enter text>";  //place holder
textFieldRounded.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; //background color
textFieldRounded.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;   // no auto correction support

textFieldRounded.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;  // type of the keyboard
textFieldRounded.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;  // type of the return key

textFieldRounded.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing; // has a clear 'x' button to the right

textFieldRounded.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

[skizzenFeldOutlet addSubview:textFieldRounded];

textFieldRounded.delegate = self;
```

I create a textfield. It works fine, but I can't put text on the textfield. The textfield is visible but I can draw in the view under the textfield!

Any tips?

Best regards
Andreas

Answer (score 0):

because of this.

[skizzenFeldOutlet addSubview:textFieldRounded];

your textField is been flat added in your view.